# How to fix the error "No such module "FirebaseAuth"

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I installed all the pods that I needed, but Xcode shows me an error "No such Module FirebaseAuth", I tried this I found:

1. Shift+ Command + K to clean the workspace
2. I reinstalled the podfile in the Terminal
3. Command + b
4. I am already in the workspace, not in the project file
5. I didn't know if that helps but I reinstalled the computer.

```swift
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
```

Here is the Pod file:

```swift
target 'Ouvrigram' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  # Pods for Ouvrigram

end
```

I installed all the pods, I checked there are installed, I don't​ know what I am to do Pls help.

Comment: WHat's the CocoaPods version you have installed on your Mac and the deployment target iOS version?

Comment: I think the latest one

Comment: What version of Cocoapods are you using? If you don't know, at the command line type the following `pod --version` and then report back the version number.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure the target name is the same as your Xcode project name ? 
Also make sure you are opening the project with the .xworkspace file. You can't use the .xcodeproj file anymore if you are using pods

Comment: yes, I opened The Workspace but that does not work.

Answer (score 3):

First click on your project on the left side then go to General tab and scroll down to Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content, click on the + and add the module that you need.

Answer (score 2):

XCode is really buggy and Apple isn't really excited about improving their compatibility with Google services. I get the same error even after importing:

- import Firebase
- import FirebaseFirestore
- import FirebaseAuth
- import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

But my project builds and runs successfully in spite of all the RED errors everywhere on my project.
In fact, a simple "import Firebase" is enough for a successful build.

XCode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Comment: If your code works in spite of the warnings, I think it would be good to also add the version of Xcode you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you forget to run the `pod init` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace content of your Podfile with Podfile-ios-objc
[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/cocoapods/Podfile-ios-objc](http://Podfile-ios-objc)

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you imported everyting needed, always try to reset packages cache!
Worked well for me

Once you are in XCode:
File -> Packages -> Reset Package Caches